# uwsgi with emperor/systemd: announcing loyalty takes up to 3 minutes

Tags: django, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, system, uwsgi

I've some strange behavior on my production machines.
I'm running Python 2.7.12 on Ubuntu 16.04. Nginx as the web server (1.10.3). I'm running a Django (1.11.15) application. UWSGI 2.0.17.1 will handle requests to the application server.

Basically, everything runs fine. Until I reboot the machine. After rebooting it takes about 3 minutes before I see the message 'announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...'.

From the moment the system restarted until the UWSGI is ready, my Nginx received 499/502 and 503 error.

I tried a lot of things to fix this issue. One of the things I did is starting the machine without starting NGinx. Wait for 3 minutes, start NGinx and then everything runs fine. So, it seems like an issue with the Emperor/Systemd.

My emperor file:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My uwsgi:

```
# d4t wsgi ini file
[uwsgi]
# master
master           = false
# maximum number of processes
processes        = 5
# threads
enable-threads   = true
# socket to use
socket           = /tmp/uwsgi-omniit.sock
# permissions
chmod-socket     = 666
# base directory
chdir            = /var/www/omni-it/omniit/
# virtualenv
virtualenv       = /var/www/omni-it/
# module
module           = omniit.wsgi:application
# buffer size: the autocomplete is a bit large in the request
buffer-size      = 8190
# user and group
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
```

After rebooting, syslog output:

```
Aug 12 18:21:45 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 5 seconds on interpreter 0x23486e0 pid: 366 (default app)
Aug 12 18:21:45 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
Aug 12 18:21:45 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 366)
Aug 12 18:21:45 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: Sun Aug 12 18:21:45 2018 - [emperor] vassal omniit_uwsgi.ini has been spawned
Aug 12 18:21:45 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 757, cores: 1)
Aug 12 18:21:45 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 758, cores: 1)
Aug 12 18:21:45 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 759, cores: 1)
Aug 12 18:21:45 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 760, cores: 1)
Aug 12 18:21:45 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 761, cores: 1)
Aug 12 18:21:45 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: Sun Aug 12 18:21:45 2018 - [emperor] vassal omniit_uwsgi.ini is ready to accept requests
Aug 12 18:21:45 tst001app20 ntpd[730]: Soliciting pool server 213.136.0.252
Aug 12 18:21:45 tst001app20 ntpd[730]: Soliciting pool server 85.255.214.66
Aug 12 18:21:45 tst001app20 ntpd[730]: Listen normally on 7 eth0 [fe80::35ff:fe33:1e%2]:123
Aug 12 18:21:45 tst001app20 ntpd[730]: new interface(s) found: waking up resolver
Aug 12 18:21:45 tst001app20 ntpd[730]: Soliciting pool server 213.109.127.82
Aug 12 18:21:45 tst001app20 ntpd[730]: receive: Unexpected origin timestamp from 83.162.177.33
Aug 12 18:21:45 tst001app20 systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Aug 12 18:21:45 tst001app20 systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 27min 21.221010s random time.
Aug 12 18:21:46 tst001app20 ntpd[730]: Soliciting pool server 213.154.229.24
Aug 12 18:21:46 tst001app20 ntpd[730]: Soliciting pool server 13.80.10.154
Aug 12 18:21:46 tst001app20 ntpd[730]: Soliciting pool server 212.114.109.139
Aug 12 18:21:46 tst001app20 ntpd[730]: Soliciting pool server 149.210.199.182
Aug 12 18:22:48 tst001app20 kernel: [   70.779037] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: Sun Aug 12 20:24:57 2018 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request / (ip 145.7.170.253) !!!
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: Sun Aug 12 20:24:57 2018 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request / (ip 145.7.170.254) !!!
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: Sun Aug 12 20:24:57 2018 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request / (ip 145.7.170.124) !!!
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: Sun Aug 12 20:24:57 2018 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request / (ip 145.7.170.124) !!!
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: Sun Aug 12 20:24:57 2018 - uwsgi_response_write_headers_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 248] during GET / (145.7.170.254)
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: Sun Aug 12 20:24:57 2018 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request / (ip 145.7.170.254) !!!
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: Sun Aug 12 20:24:57 2018 - uwsgi_response_write_headers_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 248] during GET / (145.7.170.254)
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: Sun Aug 12 20:24:57 2018 - uwsgi_response_write_headers_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 248] during GET / (145.7.170.124)
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: Sun Aug 12 20:24:57 2018 - uwsgi_response_write_headers_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 248] during GET / (145.7.170.124)
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: Sun Aug 12 20:24:57 2018 - uwsgi_response_write_headers_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 248] during GET / (145.7.170.253)
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: IOError: write error
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: [pid: 758|app: 0|req: 1/1] 145.7.170.254 () {38 vars in 451 bytes} [Sun Aug 12 20:22:35 2018] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 142151 msecs (HTTP/1.1 302) 8 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: Sun Aug 12 18:24:57 2018 - [emperor] vassal omniit_uwsgi.ini is now loyal
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: IOErrorIOError: write error
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: [pid: 757|app: 0|req: 1/2] 145.7.170.254 () {38 vars in 451 bytes} [Sun Aug 12 20:22:03 2018] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 174008 msecs (HTTP/1.1 302) 8 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: : write error
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: [pid: 759|app: 0|req: 1/3] 145.7.170.124 () {38 vars in 451 bytes} [Sun Aug 12 20:21:46 2018] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 191803 msecs (HTTP/1.1 302) 8 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: Sun Aug 12 18:24:57 2018 - [emperor] vassal omniit_uwsgi.ini is now loyal
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: Sun Aug 12 18:24:57 2018 - [emperor] vassal omniit_uwsgi.ini is now loyal
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: IOError: write error
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: [pid: 760|app: 0|req: 1/4] 145.7.170.253 () {38 vars in 451 bytes} [Sun Aug 12 20:23:50 2018] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 67595 msecs (HTTP/1.1 302) 8 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: Sun Aug 12 18:24:57 2018 - [emperor] vassal omniit_uwsgi.ini is now loyal
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: IOError: write error
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: [pid: 761|app: 0|req: 1/5] 145.7.170.124 () {38 vars in 451 bytes} [Sun Aug 12 20:22:16 2018] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 161628 msecs (HTTP/1.1 302) 8 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: Sun Aug 12 18:24:57 2018 - [emperor] vassal omniit_uwsgi.ini is now loyal
Aug 12 18:24:57 tst001app20 uwsgi[348]: [pid: 758|app: 0|req: 2/6] 145.7.170.254 () {38 vars in 451 bytes} [Sun Aug 12 20:24:57 2018] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 14 msecs (HTTP/1.1 302) 8 headers in 292 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

After this, I can just reload and restart the emperor without any problem. No errors occur anymore.

Any help would be appreciated!